# Ticket message makes \r\n in line space

Tags: php, linux, email

I have now searched for some fixing my issue but no solution. My dev gaveup long ago, so help anyone..

I have a integrated ticket system sending automatic email to user and admin when create and reply. The email header goes fine out and email ticket template also fine. But the Message included keep have this issue with line space replaced by`\r\n.`

It run on Linux server
Here is email header

```
$config['email_headers'] = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nFrom: \"sitename\" <noReply@mydomain.com>\r\nReply-To: \"NoReply\" <noreply@mydomain.com>\r\nX-Priority: 3\r\nX-Mailer: PHP 5.4";
```

Here is the function file part

```
# Email to user and admin code starts here
$sql = "select * from ".TABLE_PREFIX."emailtemplate where type='ticketreply_send' LIMIT 1";
$sth = mysql_query( $sql );
$emailtemplate = mysql_fetch_array( $sth );
$Ticket_Email = $emailtemplate['content'];
$Ticket_Email = str_replace( "[[SITE_TITLE]]", $this->config['title'], $Ticket_Email );
$Ticket_Email = str_replace( "[[ticket_id]]", $ticketId, $Ticket_Email );
$Ticket_Email = str_replace( "[[message]]", $message, $Ticket_Email );
$Ticket_Email = explode( "--- Email ---", $Ticket_Email );
$Subject = $Ticket_Email[0];
$Message = $Ticket_Email[1];
mail( $user_info['email'], $Subject, $Message, $this->config['email_headers'] );
mail( $this->config['private_sys_email'], $Subject, $Message, $this->config['email_headers'] );
# Email to user and admin code ends here
```

If you need more parts of code pls let me now.
I realy hope some of you will give it a bit time and have the answer. Thank you alot.

Comment: What 'issue' with \r\n do you have? Are they showing in plaintext, are they not working as expected? What line space?

Comment: It is better to ask clear question instead describing "issue".

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear. But If the header goes fine and the message have some *issues*, then we can operate on that.

If your problem is the `\r\n` which became a two-empty-line in the body, then add this statement *before* the `mail` call:

```
$Message = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $Message );
```

If, instead, you don't see any new line, then try

```
$Message = str_replace( "\n", "\r\n", $Message );
```